# get data patterns in HTML

Tags: html, r, path, web-crawler

my goal is to write some lines of R code which allow me to make web scraping from

[www.skyscanner.it/trasporti/voli/mila/fran/180201?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home#results](http://www.skyscanner.it/trasporti/voli/mila/fran/180201?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home#results)

getting: airline, departure and arrival airportS, departure and arrival timeS, price.

I decided to use the Rcrawler package ([here how it works](https://github.com/salimk/Rcrawler)) but, having no experience of HTML, i've no idea of how to set the ExtractXpathPat option to get data.

```
    Rcrawler(Website = "https://www.skyscanner.it/trasporti/voli/mila/fran/180201?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=day-view#results", 
no_cores = 4, no_conn = 4, ExtractXpathPat = c("?????"))
```

What should i do? How can i learn how to set path?
Thanks!

Comment: try rvest package : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf

Answer (score 1):

**Be careful according to the policy of the domain is not allowed to extract through web scraping the information**. However to get the css code or the xpath you can use "[Selector Gadget](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html)" or the inspect button in your browser.

To make sure web scraping is allowed you must visit the robots.txt of the domain. In your case: http://www.skyscanner.com/robots.txt. You can also use `robotstxt` package.